# bash & jq: add attribute with object value

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm looking for a solution to add a new attribute with a JSON object value into an existing JSON file.

My current script:

```bash
if [ ! -f "$src_file" ]; then
  echo "Source file $src_file does not exists"
  exit 1
fi
if [ ! -f "$dst_file" ]; then
  echo "Destination file $dst_file does not exists"
  exit 1
fi

if ! jq '.devDependencies' "$src_file" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "The key "devDependencies" does not exists into source file $src_file"
  exit 1
fi

dev_dependencies=$(jq '.devDependencies' "$src_file" | xargs )

# Extract data from source file
data=$(cat $src_file)

# Add new key-value
data=$(echo $data | jq --arg key "devDependencies" --arg value "$dev_dependencies" '. + {($key): ($value)}')

# Write data into destination file
echo $data > $dst_file
```

It's working but the `devDependencies` value from `$dev_dependencies` is wrote as string:

`"devDependencies": "{ @nrwl/esbuild: 15.6.3, @nrwl/eslint-pl[...]"`.

How can I write it as raw JSON ?

Comment: Note that `echo $data |` is itself buggy for the reasons described in [I just assigned a variable. Why does `echo $variable` show something different!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else); _always_ use `echo "$data" | ...`, or even better, either `... <<<"$data"` or `printf '%s\n' "$data" | ...`

Comment: Can you provide the (shortened) src file and expected dst file?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy or simply `<"$src_file" jq ...` or `jq ... "$src_file"` – no need to store the content of the file in a variable, just have jq read it directly. Pipes exist, variables can (and should) be avoided in most cases

Comment: Note that `xargs` produces output which is not valid JSON. Please provided actual (shortened) input and expected output

Comment: You might find https://stackoverflow.com/q/75391973/112968 helpful

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the `--argjson` option instead of `--arg`. Compare

```
$ jq --arg k '{"foo": "bar"}' -n '{x: $k}'
{
  "x": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"
}
```

with

```
$ jq --argjson k '{"foo": "bar"}' -n '{x: $k}'
{
  "x": {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`--arg` will create a *string* variable. Use `--argjson` to parse the value as JSON (can be object, array or number).

From the [docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq):

> ###### `--arg name value`:
>
> This option passes a value to the jq program as a predefined variable.
> If you run jq with `--arg foo bar`, then `$foo` is available in the
> program and has the value `"bar"`. Note that `value` will be treated as a
> string, so `--arg foo 123` will bind `$foo` to `"123"`.
>
> Named arguments are also available to the jq program as `$ARGS.named`.
>
> ###### `--argjson name JSON-text`:
>
> This option passes a JSON-encoded value to the jq program as a
> predefined variable. If you run jq with `--argjson foo 123`, then $foo
> is available in the program and has the value `123`.

Note that you don't need multiple invocations of jq, xargs, command substitution or variables (don't forget to quote all your variables when expanding).

To "merge" the contents of two files, read both files with jq and let jq do the work. This avoids all the complications that arise from jumping between jq and shell context. A single line is all that's needed:

```
jq --slurpfile deps "$dep_file" '. + { devDependencies: $deps[0].devDependencies }' "$source_file" > "$dest_file"
```

or

```
jq --slurpfile deps "$dep_file" '. + ($deps[0]|{devDependencies})' "$source_file" > "$dest_file"
```

alternatively (still a one-liner):

```
jq --slurpfile deps "$dev_file" '.devDependencies = $deps[0].devDependencies' "$source_file" > "$dest_file"
```

[peak's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75392237/112968) reminded me of the very useful [`input`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#input) filter, which can make the program even shorter as it avoids the variable:

```
jq '. + (input|{devDependencies})' "$source_file" "$dep_file" > "$dest_file"
```