# Transfer or merge only some properties from one JSON file to another with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have two JSON files:

```
$ jq . a.json b.json 
{
  "id": "ZGVhZGJlZWY=",
  "name": "first file",
  "version": 1,
  "description": "just a simple json file"
}
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "fake name",
  "dependencies": [
    4,
    2
  ],
  "comment": "I'm just sitting here, ignore me"
}
```

and want to merge them into a single file (think of file 1 as "template" and file 2 as "actual values"). I don't want to merge all properties, I only want to transfer some properties of the second file (specifically only `version` and `dependencies`). `version` should overwrite the value in the original file and `dependencies` should be added to the new file. `name` must not be overwritten and the original name must be kept.

This is the expected result:

```
{
  "id": "ZGVhZGJlZWY=",
  "name": "first file",
  "version": 2,
  "description": "just a simple json file",
  "dependencies": [
    4,
    2
  ]
}
```

I know that jq supports the `+` and `*` operators to merge or merge recursively, but how can I apply those to only some properties and not all? How can I access both files in my jq program; do I have to preprocess the file and then use `--arg` in a second jq call?

Obviously, `jq '. + {version, dependencies}' a.json b.json` does not work. What is the correct program here?

What would the solution look like if `description` should also be dropped from the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want simplicity, brevity, and efficiency, consider:

```
jq '. + (input|{version, dependencies})' a.json b.json
```

If the first file might have .dependencies, and if in that case you want to add in the second file's:

```
jq '. as $a | input as $b | $a + ($b|{version}) | .dependencies += $b.dependencies'
```

To drop .description, you could append `| del(.description)` to either of these filters.

Comment: Thanks, I always forget about the very useful `input` filter. "One input == one file", is that correct? Or is there special care required if the file contains multiple entities?

Comment: One `input` reads one JSON entity.  It is the singular of `inputs` :-)

Comment: I tried with `b.json` containing two JSON entities (i.e. a stream of two JSON objects). This will abort with an error (but still output a result). Using a variable would always use the first entity (with `.[0]`) or build the product with `.[]`.

Comment: If b.json has two JSON entities, then after the first of these has been read, `.` will read the second, and then `input` will fail.  What did you expect?

Comment: I'd expect `input` to return the first entity of the file; looks like my expectation is wrong/unrealastic. But `.` will always read the first file, `input` the file after, no? I guess my confusion comes from "does `input` read a file or an entity and how does it read a file with multiple entities?"

Comment: Are you expecting `input` to backtrack???  It doesn't.  `input, input` would read two entities if there are two.  You might like to look at how `inputs` is implemented.  By the way, using `first(inputs)` is sometimes preferable to using `input` as the latter gives an error if there is nothing to read.

Comment: But there is something to read?? I'm simply not reading all. I have 3 entities (1 entity in file a, 2 entities in file b). Now, with program `[., input]` I get an error (»jq: error (at ...): break«), but I'd expect none: there are enough entities to read. `[., input, input]` works. `[., input, input, input]` doesn't either, but that's what I would expect.

Comment: To get a better understanding, try using debug, e.g. `[debug, "input: \(input)"]`

Answer (score 1):

`+` or `*` can be used here, correct. Let's first see how `+` works:

```
$ jq -n '{a:1,b:2} + {b:3,c:4}'
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 3,
  "c": 4
}
```

- Properties only present in the left object are kept
- Properties of the right object overwrite properties of the left object
- Properties only present in the right object are added

Perfect, now how to get the objects from two unrelated files? [`--slurpfile`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Invokingjq) can be used, which reads all JSON entities in the file into an array and puts it into a variable.

```
$ jq --slurpfile b b.json '. + $b[0]' a.json
{
  "id": "ZGVhZGJlZWY=",
  "name": "fake name",
  "version": 2,
  "description": "just a simple json file",
  "dependencies": [
    4,
    2
  ],
  "comment": "I'm just sitting here, ignore me"
}
```

We are getting closer, but are not quite there yet. `name` is overwritten and `comment` is added; both of which we do not want. To solve this, we can transform the slurped object into a new object which only contains the properties we care about

```
$ jq --slurpfile b b.json '. + ($b[0] | {version,dependencies})' a.json
{
  "id": "ZGVhZGJlZWY=",
  "name": "first file",
  "version": 2,
  "description": "just a simple json file",
  "dependencies": [
    4,
    2
  ]
}
```

---

Now let's address part two of the question: "can some properties of the first file be dropped?"

There are basically two options:

1. Creating a new object containing only the required properties and then adding the second object (any property part of the second file can be ignored, since it will be added anyway): `{id,name} + ($b[0] | {version,dependencies})`
2. Deleting the unneeded properties: `del(.description) + ($b[0] | {version,dependencies})` or `. + ($b[0] | {version,dependencies}) | del(.description)`

Depending on the number of properties you want to keep/drop, one or the other solution might be simpler to use. Creating a new object has the advantage of being able to rename properties in one go.

Executing solution 2:

```
$ jq --slurpfile b b.json 'del(.description) + ($b[0] | {version,dependencies})' a.json
{
  "id": "ZGVhZGJlZWY=",
  "name": "first file",
  "version": 2,
  "dependencies": [
    4,
    2
  ]
}
```