# Recursive merge JSON string with file using jq

Tags: bash, stream, jq

I have a bash string `default` with content

```
$ echo $default
{
    "horses": {
        "count": 0,
        "fizz": "buzz"
    },
    "admin": {
        "enabled": false
    }
}
```

and a file `override.json` with content

```
$ cat override.json
{
    "horses": {
        "count": 1,
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    "admin": {
        "enabled": true
    }
}
```

I want to recursively merge these using `jq` to produce the result

```
{
    "horses": {
        "count": 1,
        "foo": "bar",
        "fizz": "buzz"
    },
    "admin": {
        "enabled": true
    }
}
```

I've tried to understand the docs and a few things like

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' $(echo $default) override.json
```

but my bash and stream skills are limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incidentally, your `default` variable is *almost* (!) valid jq program/filter (albeit not valid JSON). If you quote the value in the `fizz:buzz` line (change to `fizz: "buzz"`), then you could use it directly as the LHS of the recursive-merge operator:

```
jq "$default * ." override.json
```

---

With the updated question (which now has valid JSON in the `default` variable), jq should be invoked as follows:

```
jq --argjson defaults "$default" '$defaults * .' override.json
```

Comment: How is the line `fizz: buzz` valid jq? You'd at least need something along the lines of `jq "def buzz: \"buzz\"; $default * ." override.json`.

Comment: @pmf you are right, I missed that the string value was not quoted. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thank you! Look so simple now that i see it.

Comment: (The non-valid JSON was a error from my part obfuscating my real data. Edited my question now.)

Comment: @blueski Generally speaking, you should very much avoid injecting data into code, as jq offers plenty of possibilities to do it in a safe manner. One would be using the `--argjson` option: `jq --argjson default "$default" '$default * .' override.json`. Less concise, yet way less error-prone as well.

Comment: With the updated question, this becomes more or less a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75391973/transfer-or-merge-only-some-properties-from-one-json-file-to-another-with-jq (only merging all properties)

Answer (score 1):

[stedolan/jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) would be a good choice to process JSON content. But the content of `$default` is not valid JSON (it lacks string quoting, coompare it to the file's content which *is* valid JSON).

However, the variable's content is valid YAML (a superset of JSON), so using a YAML-processor will work. Here are a few options:

##### Using [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq):

```bash
gojq --yaml-input --slurpfile in override.json '. * $in[0]' <<< "$default"
```

```json
{
  "admin": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "horses": {
    "count": 1,
    "fizz": "buzz",
    "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

##### Using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```bash
yq --argfile in override.json '. * $in' <<< "$default"
```

```json
{
  "horses": {
    "count": 1,
    "fizz": "buzz",
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  "admin": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

##### Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```bash
yq -o json '. * load("override.json")' <<< "$default"
```

```json
{
  "horses": {
    "count": 1,
    "fizz": "buzz",
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  "admin": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The non-valid JSON was a error from my part obfuscating my real data. I edited my question now.